# WebSocket API code

Tags: javascript, websocket

I am using WebSocket API in html5. That API has an inbuilt function for sending data to the websocket.
Usage is ws.send().I want to know where i can get the code for that inbuilt function.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open source WebSocket send() implementations:

- [Firefox](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/content/base/src/WebSocket.cpp#1172)
- [Chromium/Chrome](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/blink/trunk/Source/modules/websockets/WebSocket.cpp?revision=166474) (starting at line 390)

Answer (score 0):

well , it depends on the impelementation, Internet explorer has its own, so do Chrome. if you want to see the code of that function, probably you can do it looking at Firefox code, which is open source.  [you can navigate through the code here](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/)
and I think what you're looking for is [here](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/content/base/src/WebSocket.cpp)